# Google-RISC security event is not getting fired for my G-suite email

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-oauth, secevents

I have implemented google oauth login and google RISC security event handling for our app. To enable oauth, I have created web app on google console using our G suite email address.

After enabling the Sec event for this app. I did oauth login using my same G-suite email address. To test sec event I revoked the app access for my email account. At this stage I did not receive sec event.

If I execute the same steps with my other personal email then I am able to receive security event.

Even I was able to receive test event that is mentioned in the documentation(https://schemas.openid.net/secevent/risc/event-type/verification). Not sure if something to do with our g suite account.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why am I not receiving Google security events for G Suite accounts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58806916/why-am-i-not-receiving-google-security-events-for-g-suite-accounts)
                 
I ran into the same issue and had google support tell me to post here on SO before updating their docs to say `"Cross-Account Protection does not currently send security events for G Suite users."`

Answer (score 0):

Google's [documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/risc) for Cross Account Protection says:

> **Note:** Cross-Account Protection does not currently send security events for Google Workspace (formerly G Suite) users.

Until this changes, you won't get RISC security events for Google Workspace accounts.